# FullCalendar renderEvent v2 Beta2

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm starting to play around with the v2 Beta2 of FullCalendar and I'm not sure if I'm using the control incorrectly or if there's a potential bug.  Basically when I add a moment() object with a specific hour the full calendar renders the event in what looks like UTC format?  So setting the start hour to be 9 and end hour to be 10 the fullCalendar control ends up rendering it 2pm - 3pm.   Thoughts on whether I'm using the moment() object incorrectly or using the fullCalender incorrectly or if it's a bug in v2 Beta2?

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        var event = {
            title: 'new event',
            start: moment({ hour: 9 }),
            end: moment({ hour: 10 }),
        };
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent",event);
    });

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar();
});</script><button type="button" id="btn">Click for action</button><div id="calendar"</div>
```